# Read dynamic HTML elements using R

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, google-visualization

First of all, I'd like to say that I am completely new to R. I've read the documentation and cannot find a way to fix the following scenario:

I have made a chart using google charts library (org-chart) and it works. The thing is that every node in the hierarchy has an input that I have to read and send to R when the user clicks a button or clicks enter. And here are my problems

1. I don't know how to set reactivity to the dynamically created nodes
2. I don't knwo how many nodes do I have to read because they are completely random. My idea is to set a class on every node and iterate later but I am not sure.

What I have done just to test is:

```
library(shiny)
# Define server logic for random distribution application
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$num <- renderText ({
        paste('Number has changed to : ', input$qty_1)
      })
})
```

where $qty_1 is

```
<input name="qty_1" id="qty_1" value="10" type="number"></input>
```

But no luck.

P.S. I am using Shiny framework to develop the backend.

My HTML is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        input[type="number"] {
            background-color : #fdfdd2;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
    "use strict";
        var tree = {
            name: "ROOT",
            desc: "Root",
            qty : 0,
            parent: '',
            children: {
                name: "FIRST",
                desc: "first",
                qty : 0,
                parent: 'ROOT',
                children: [{
                    name: "SECOND",
                    desc: "second",
                    qty : 0,
                    parent: 'FIRST',
                    children: {}
                }, {
                    name: "THIRD",
                    desc: "third",
                    qty : 0,
                    parent: 'FIRST',
                    children: [{
                        name: "FOURTH",
                        desc: "fourth",
                        qty: 0,
                        parent: 'THIRD',
                        children:{}
                    },{
                        name: "FIFTH",
                        desc: "fifth",
                        qty : 0,
                        parent: 'THIRD',
                        children: [{
                            name: "SIXTH",
                            desc: "sixth",
                            qty : 0,
                            parent: 'FIFTH',
                            children: {}
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Desc');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Qty');

            // For each orgchart box, provide the name, description, and quantity to show.
            addRows(data, tree);

            // Create the chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
            chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });
        }

        function addRows(data, Tree) {
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(Tree)) return;

            appendToChart(data, Tree.name, Tree.desc, Tree.qty, Tree.parent);

            var children = Tree.children;

            if (Object.prototype.toString.call( children ) == '[object Array]'){ // more than 1 child
                for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    addRows(data, children[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                addRows(data, children);
            }
        }

        function appendToChart(data, name, desc, qty, parent) {
            data.addRows([
                //[name, parent, desc]
                [{ v:name, f: name + '<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">' + desc + 
                    '</div><input id="qty" size="4" value="' + qty + '" type="number"></input>' }, parent, desc]
            ]);
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="chart_div"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13)
                if ($.isNumeric($("#qty").val()))
                    alert($("#qty").val());
                else
                    alert("not a number");
        });
    });
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you could try:

1. add the shiny.js to your `head` (I generally also put the shiny jquery version):

   `<script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

   `<script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
2. Wrap your numeric inputs in a `<div class="shiny-input-container">` so that shiny recognizes them as inputs and binds them, they will need a name attribute that you can then use to refer to them in the `server.R`. For ex, you could do in your `addRows` function:

`[{ v:name, f: name + '<div style="color:red; font-style:italic" >' + desc + 
                    '</div><div class="shiny-input-container"><input name="qty-'+name+'" size="4" value="' + qty + '" type="number"></input></div>' }, parent, desc]`

3. Since you are adding inputs by js, you should call `Shiny.unbindAll()` at the beginning at the `drawChart` function and `Shiny.bindAll()` at the end to get all the Shiny input bindings working.

In the server.R you can then refer to the inputs, they will all have a name like `qty-name`, you can filter them out of the input list by doing `grepl("qty",names(input))`. For example to print them all you could do, in `server.R`:

```
observe({
   lapply(names(input)[grepl("qty",names(input))],function(x){
        print(paste(x,input[[x]]))
   })
})
```

Comment: @Nice, hope you are doing good. I was hoping you would be able to help me with reading a dynamic html output in viewer pane in Shiny app. I have posted a question on this, sorry for getting in touch in this way and hope you would be able to help. Link to my post is -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991183/crosstab-output-getting-displayed-in-viewer-pane-only-and-not-in-shiny-app