# crosstab output getting displayed in viewer pane only and not in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, crosstab, sjplot

I am generating a cross table output (contingency table). My requirement is to have column percentages along with row and column totals. I found this package **"sjPlot"** which gives very good output with colour features and was meeting my requirement. I used this package to generate the output in Shiny. But to my surprise the output is getting generated only in the viewer pane and not in the app. Below is a small part of my code.

```
library("shiny")
library("sjPlot")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tabPanel("First Page"),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id='mytabs',
                        tabPanel("Table",tags$b(tags$br("Table Summary" )),tags$br(),dataTableOutput("crosstab2"))
                        )
            )
  ))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  updateTabsetPanel(session = session
                    ,inputId = 'myTabs')

  output$crosstab2 <- renderDataTable({
      with(mtcars,sjt.xtab(mpg, cyl,
                        var.labels = c("mpg","cyl"),
                        show.col.prc = T,
                        show.summary = F,
                        show.na = F,
                        wrap.labels = 50,
                        tdcol.col = "#f90477",
                        emph.total = T,
                        emph.color = "#3aaee0",
                        #use.viewer = T ##when this is false it generates a html output. Can we capture the html output and display in Shiny?
                        CSS = list(css.table = "border: 1px solid;",
                                   css.tdata = "border: 1px solid;")))      
    })

    print("created crosstab1")    
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This generates the needed output in viewer pane. How can I get this output displayed in the app. I can not save this output as a image as in my actual program the variables are getting selected dynamically and the table output accordingly changes.

Comment: I;ve never used the `sjPlot` package so how are you dealing with the error about unused arguments when you simply plot it in base R?

Comment: @Pork, I have run the above code in r studio and I am not getting any error. The output gets generated in viewer pane and not in the Shiny app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sjt.xtab`invisibly returns a list that contains the html and css used to generate the table that you see in the viewer.

You can use `htmlOutput` on the ui side and `renderUI` on the server side to display it.

In your `ui.R`, you can use:

```
htmlOutput("crosstab2")
```

In your `server.R`:

```
  output$crosstab2 <- renderUI({
    custom_table <- sjt.xtab(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl,variableLabels = c("mpg","cyl"),showColPerc = T,
                             showSummary = F,showNA=F,highlightTotal = T,tdcol.col = "#f90477", highlightColor ="#3aaee0",
                             CSS = list(css.table = "border: 1px solid;",
                                        css.tdata = "border: 1px solid;"))
    HTML(custom_table$knitr)
  })
```

Here's (part of) my `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sjPlot_1.9.2 shiny_0.13.1
```

I suspect we don't have the same version of `sjPlot` as the arguments of the `sjt.xtab` you use in your example have changed names.

Comment: thank you a very much for your answer!! You are So ready to help :) !! Yes my version of **sjPlot is 2.1.2** so there might be come difference in arguments. For my understanding, could you please confirm why you use renderUI though we are generating a table. I was using renderDataTable considering that we are generating a table output. How should we conclude which render function to use? Then how did you figure out that **sjt.xtab** invisibly returns a list that contains the html and css used to generate the table. Thank you once again!!

Comment: `renderDataTable` is used to render data frames, if you look at `?sjt.xtab`, in the Value part, you will see that it does not return a data frame so `renderDataTable` is not the right rendering function. The function returns html so the right function is `renderUi`/`htmlOutput`. I edit the code, you can directly use `custom_table$knitr` as it has inlince CSS.

Comment: thank you!! I understand. This is working for dynamic variable selection as well. The table is getting updated!!